# ruby - extend module inside another module

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to define a couple of modules to easily add in some instance and class methods to other classes, here's what I'm doing:

```
module Foo
  module Bar
    def speak
      puts "hey there"
    end
  end
  module Baz
    extend Foo::Bar

    def welcome
      puts "welcome, this is an instance method"
    end
  end
end

class Talker
  include Foo::Baz
end

Talker.new.welcome
Talker.speak
```

The output of this is:

```
welcome, this is an instance method
undefined method 'speak' for Talker.class (NoMethodError)
```

I was expecting Talker to have the 'speak' method since it includes Foo::Baz which itself extends Foo::Bar.

What am I missing?

Comment: so if I make Baz a class instead of a module and I change Talker so it subclasses Baz, my example works. But is it possible to do what I was trying to do without making Baz a class? (and without having to do something like Talker::Foo::Bar.speak?)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try this:

```
module Baz
  extend Foo::Bar

  def self.included(base)
    base.send :extend, Foo::Bar
  end

  def welcome
    puts "welcome, this is an instance method"
  end
end
```

This will auto-extend all classes in wich Baz is included.

PS:

`extend Foo::Bar` in `module Baz` was in original snippet, this code do not influence on method `def self.included(base)`.

Comment: Why 2 extend Foo::Bar? one is inside included and one is outside.

Comment: First extend adds class level methods from Foo::Bar to Baz. Second one adds methods from Foo::Bar to all classes and modules which include Baz.

Comment: I still don't see how `extend Foo::Bar` is useful in this or maybe any other context

Comment: `extend Foo::Bar` was in original code snippet, so I decided to leave it here. Really it is not necessary for this situation. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
class Talker
   extend Foo::Baz
end
```

since you want to call Talker.speak as a class method and not as an instance method (like Talker.new.speak) you have to include the Foo:Baz in a way that the class will take the methods itself.

One possibility is to use 'extend' (as above) the other is modifying it's eigenclass:

```
class Talker
  class << self
    include Foo::Baz
  end
end
```